# Unable to import python modules from a python file in google collab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

!python3.6 abc.py

I am trying to execute the above line of code in google collab.
abc.py contains modules imported like NumPy, sklearn. Recently, I am getting this error in collab :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "abc.py", line 1, in <module>
import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

This error had never occurred on my previous usages of this code. Please help.

Comment: If it has worked before its most likely a setting/configuration issue.

Comment: You will have to install numpy and maybe other dependencies as well.

Answer (score 0):

install the packages listed in your file using

```
pip install <package_name>
```

safe to install them in virtual environment.

Make sure you have activated virtual environment if you are using one already.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `conda install numpy`